# How to import ubottu factoids database to my IRC supybot?

Tags: irc

I am using supybot. Can anyone say me the procedure for adding ubottu factoids database to my IRC bot? I found the ubottu factoids database here http://www.ubottu.com/factoids.cgi

I want to add this database to my IRC bot. Can anyone tell me the procedure?

Comment: I think we have to create a table using sqlite2 and after that we have to place the database file in appropriate location.But i am not sure about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu Factoids uses the Encyclopedia plugin. Get it from **bzr branch lp:ubuntu-bots** and then download Ubuntu factoids database from [here](http://ubottu.com/factoids.cgi). Place your database in the data directory (i.e /supybot/data/). You should point to the location of the database in your bot configuration. Be sure that you enable Encyclopedia plugin by typing **load Encyclopedia**. Also you should have `sqlite` installed in your system.

## [sqlite](http://packages.ubuntu.com/sqlite) [image: Install sqlite]

You can also create your own database. Open a terminal and type **sqlite** and copy / paste the following in terminal.

```
CREATE TABLE factoids ( 
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        author VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
        name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        added DATETIME,
        value VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
        popularity INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

Answer (score 3):

ubottu uses the Encyclopedia plugin to manage its factoids, not the 'Factoid' plugin that comes with supybot itself.  You can download the current bot code by running `bzr branch lp:ubuntu-bots`, more information about the bot code can be found on its [launchpad page](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-bots/ubuntu-bots/devel).

Either drop all the subfolders that you get after branching the bzr repo into your bot plugin directory or create a new one and add that path into `supybot.directories.plugins`

After loading Encyclopedia inside supybot, you'll need to modify your settings so that it knows where your factoid database is.  The important config values for that are `plugins.encyclopedia.datadir` and `plugins.encyclopedia.database` . If you don't set these, it will use your bot's data directory and `ubuntu` as the database name. (note: the database name should be entered without the `.db` extension)

Comment: Thankyou also say me how to delete the factoid keys.A single factoid has many keys how delete a particular key.

Answer (score 1):

The factois db (sqlite2 format as used by the factoids plugin) is available at http://www.ubottu.com/ubuntu.db . I never used supybot, but basically you will need to enable the Factoids plugin and place the db renaming it to the channel name you want it to work on.

Comment: Already tried this it din work.

Comment: Also say me how to customize error reports..?